# issue with \subsubheading with nested syntax

Tags: article

I am back with another issue. This time it is an ! Undefined control sequence for the following section of text:

```
\subsubsection{\texbf{ \underline{Scenario 1 Path Loss:}}}
```

In this scenario, we consider the following issues associated with the model:

If I comment out the \subsubsection the error disappears, but I can't figure out what is wrong with the syntax. Can someone throw some light?

TIA

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please take a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for guidelines for formatting questions, in particular the advice about providing a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and how to set off chunks of code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The error message starts with `Undefined control sequence` and in the line below it the undefined command is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the `\subsubsection` line is that `\textbf` is misspelled as `\texbf`.

Comment: thanks....sometimes it doesn't take a lot for one to feel stupid!

Comment: Using an editor that has LaTeX syntax highlighting and shortcuts for common commands can prevent some of these headaches. Check out [these reviews](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) of various editors.